# How can I replace the existing files with InnoSetup?

Tags: inno-setup

How can I replace the existing files if user tries to run a "Updater" instead of "Installer"
I mean user already installed a software, and I want him to run a "Updater" to replace some of files in installation directory.

I tried it with below code but the existing files stay the same.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\MyApp\bin\GUI\*";         DestDir: "{app}\MyApp\bin\GUI"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

Comment: Your code is correct. It just works. Show us installer log, if not.

Comment: Ah. This time works. Probably other part of a script caused it not to do correctly. I removed many statements. So, Basically, InnoSetup replaces files if there are already, and otherwise tries to copy? Is it right? Thanks for your help.

Comment: With `ignoreversion`, it just copies the files always. It does not matter if the files exists or not. Consider deleting your question.

Comment: Glad you didn't delete your question, it just answered mine.